# how to break a line in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a div in which two variables value have to be displayed in different line. I have tried a lot of things but nothing is working please help...

```
this.element.className = 'key';

this.element.id = noteName;
this.element.innerHTML = noteName; 
this.element.innerHTML +=keyName;
```

Comment: Did you try inserting "<br>" ? What's you element ?

Comment: yeah i have tried <br> elemet is div

Comment: Include `\n` in `keyname` to generate a multi-line `String` i.e. `var n = 'How to break\n a line'`

Comment: you can try two spans with display: block css style.
Other better option will be to use list elements with list-style:none so that you don't see the bullet points.